# Check SOAP webservices connectivity

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am developing a monitoring tool(web application) to check the webservices that i have exposed, are correctly functioning or not.So that when i click on the link, it calls the webservices URL and check for its availability.

I can incorporate a dummy method in the webservice class and write the code for checking the same.But without this what would be an even simpler method to test the connectivity? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between connectivity and availability. Namely you could still connect to a service, even though its throwing some kind of exception (and therefore its not available).

What 'Available' means differs per service, and can only truly be checked by incorporating some kind of test method in the service which returns an OK state if everything is ok.

Connectivity is relatively easy to check, IF you can open a connection to a service: Its there, there is no real need to actually call a method on the service.